# Repeat Mono with webclient from SpringFlux

Tags: java, spring, mono, project-reactor, flux

The Situation is the following:
I sent the first request, then I sent repeatedly the second request with interval 5s. If the second request takes the success response, I save it in the database and do some actions, if it takes the not success(complete) response the request should be repeated. I need to stop repeating the second request when attempts will be bigger than 3. How I can do this?

```
     return firstRequestSenderService.send(request)
        .flatMap(resp -> {
          AtomicInteger attempts = new AtomicInteger(0);
          String url = normalizeUrl(resp.getResult());
          return Mono.defer(() -> {
            log.info("Second request, attempt = {}, params = {}", attempts.get(), param);
            return secondRequestSenderService.send(param, url, attempts.getAndIncrement());
          })
              .filter(this::isCompleteResponse)
              // i try .filter(b -> attempts.get() > 2)
              .doOnNext(r -> log.info("Save report"))
              .map(secondResp -> dataSaver.saveReport(param, secondResp))
              .doOnNext(r -> log.info("Send request to another service"))
              .flatMap(r -> secondRequestSender.sendPdf(r)))
              .doOnNext(bytes -> dataSaver.saveAnotherReport(param, bytes))
              .repeatWhenEmpty(req -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
// also try   .repeatWhenEmpty(3, req -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
        })
        .then(Mono.empty());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [reactor-addons](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/b44f8f4bc428d098fb41ab8d002f325f6f91055a/reactor-extra/src/test/java/reactor/retry) 
you can do something like that

```
    return firstRequestSenderService.send(request)
        .flatMap(resp -> {
          return secondRequestSenderService
                  .send(param, url, attempts.getAndIncrement())
                  .retryWhen(Retry.any()
                          .randomBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(100), Duration.ofMillis(5000))
                          .retryMax(3));

        });
```

also u can do that with reactor core retry utils [RetryBackoffSpec](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/retry/RetryBackoffSpec.html) you will get that when you use latest spring webflux

```
  RetryBackoffSpec retryBackoffSpec = Retry
        .fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
return firstRequestSenderService.send(request)
        .flatMap(resp -> {
                  return secondRequestSenderService
                          .send(param, url, attempts.getAndIncrement())
                          .retryWhen(retryBackoffSpec);
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works) But if I can't use this additional library, how can I do this with help of base methods?

Comment: Thanks, it is really well that the latest version has this class) But in the previous versions there aren't methods to do this. I want to see how it can be done with the help of base methods. And why for example this version `.repeatWhenEmpty(3, req -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))); ` doesn't work?